When does Simulation Equivalent imply Bisimulation
Here, Given 2 Kripke structures M1 and M2, if there exists a simulation from M1 to M2 and a simulation from M2 to M1, is there a bisimulation from M1 to M2?, it is shown that for two LTSs M1 and M2 that if M1 is simulated by M2 and vice versa this does not necessarily imply M1 and M2 are bisimilar. My question is, are there conditions under which this is true.
